# How is work done in a collision if the action reaction pair forces doesn't act over a distance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

If

> $Work= Fd$

and work and energy are interchangeable. How do we say there's work done during a collision even though the reaction-action pair forces act instantaneously, then disappear, and don't act over a distance?

I know that if a change in velocity happens then there must be work done and that the kinetic energy equation: $\frac{1}{2}m(v^2-u^2)$— comes from the integration of $W=Fd$. My teacher proved it to my class.

But how can we use the kinetic energy equation when the force didn't act over a distance in the first place? In other words, the displacement is zero so should the work.

Or do they act but it's too small or what actually happens over a microscopic level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can we use the kinetic energy equation when the force didn't
> act over a distance in the first place? In other words, the
> displacement is zero so should the work.

In a collision the displacement may be very small, but the displacement is never zero. It would only be zero for a perfectly rigid body, which does not exist at the macroscopic level.

All real bodies have some "give", meaning they undergo a certain degree of elastic deformation. So the distance over which the forces act is that associated with the compression and decompression of the bodies while they are in contact. Think of the colliding bodies as springs that compress and decompress during a collision.

So when you apply the work energy principle in the equation

$$W_{net}=F_{ave}d=\frac{1}{2}(v^{2}-u^{2})$$

The greater the average impact force the less the distance over which it acts, and vice versa, for a given change in kinetic energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if *A* and *B* collide. *A* will push on *B* compressing *B*'s molecules but the molecules don't want to come closer to each other so they will push on *A* "reaction pair"... or is this the normal contact force I'm describing and not newton third law of motion (I'm a little bit confused here tbh).... Anyway but if some of the work done by each particle over the other goes into compression does that imply then that elastic collisions don't exist???

Comment: When A and B collide, A exerts an impact force on B and B exerts an equal and opposite impact force on A, per Newton's third law. Each colliding object compresses and decompresses. If the collision is perfectly elastic, no kinetic energy is lost due to compression and decompression. But since no collision is perfectly elastic, some kinetic energy will be lost mostly as dissipated heat.

Answer (score 0):

You're right! Real collisions actually take place over a short time (and thus a short distance). Has your teacher mentioned impulse yet?

You know from calculus that the differential form of velocity is

$$ \text{d}v = v'(t) \: \text{d}t = a(t) \: \text{d}t \text{ .} $$

Using this, we can look at the time integral of Newton's Second Law as

$$ \int F(t) \: \text{d}t = \int m \: a(t) \: \text{d}t = \int m \: \text{d}v $$

and thus in differential form

$$ F \: \text{d}t = m\: \text{d}v $$

which is the impulse equation. It states that a small change in momentum will be caused by a force acting over a small time.